# Changing merchant email and phone number in emails sent fromm PayPal

Tags: paypal

I am using SetExpressCheckout and merchant contact information is incorrect.
Email and phone number are wrong.

When I talked with PayPal customer support, they told me that this is problem with the integration?

Answer (score 0):

Steps that we followed were:

- Go to Profile > My business info > Business information, then click
  Update
- Click Edit on Your business information section
- Edit desired information and click Save.

Mysteriously new entered data was overridden (can't find the reason why) so I have created new API credentials and data in emails is now correct.